# UISegmentedControl only changes its value when I tap on the segmenteddcontrol a couple of times?

Tags: xcode

so I am having this problem on `Xcode` where there is a `UISegmentedControl`.
I also put an `IBAction` (valueChanged) on the control.
The problem is that when I click on an index, the index doesn't get registered, but if I click on the other index and then back on the previous index, it will be registered.
(e.g. `0` and `1` are indexes, if I click on `0`, then on `1` and then on `0` again, the `0` will be registered)
I hope you have a solution to this.

Thanks.

Comment: What I understands is that you try to click already selected or enabled segmented control. If it is right, then this is the expected behavior as no index value is changed as you tap on selected index :)

Comment: Don't worry, I solved it. I was putting the touchevent method in the segmentedcontrol method, so there might have been a problem related to that.